# how to loop/iterate the query by getting values from an array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, nosql-aggregation

Suppose I want to get data through multiple find queries on the same object, so I created an array of that object and pass every element by iterating through the loop, but it's not working.

Example:

Instead of writing below 6 queries to monogDB prompt

```
db.Status.find({"code_id":"26"}, {"Name":1, "AMOUNT":1})
db.Status.find({"code_id":"81"}, {"Name":1, "AMOUNT":1})
db.Status.find({"code_id":"85"}, {"Name":1, "AMOUNT":1})
db.Status.find({"code_id":"19"}, {"Name":1, "AMOUNT":1})
db.Status.find({"code_id":"14"}, {"Name":1, "AMOUNT":1})
db.Status.find({"code_id":"71"}, {"Name":1, "AMOUNT":1})
```

What i tried is create an array of code_id

```
var ar = ["26","81","85","19","14","71"]
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
var obj = db.Status.find({"code_id## Heading ##":ar[i]}, {"Name":1, "AMOUNT":1});
print(obj);
};
```

I have also been through forEach loop, but have no idea that how to pass value from array to query.

Comment: You can find all of these in one query, using `$in`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but i want to discover this method to run query.

Comment: What does "_discover this method to run [the] query_" mean? @nimrodserok gave you the answer: use [the `$in` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/). Eg `db.status.find({code_id: { $in: ["26","81" ...] } }, {"Name":1, "AMOUNT":1})`